# RSS Feeds to be implemented with images

Tags: php, web, rss, phpbb

I have a php website which contain a set of forums. I would like to add latest articles on specific topics in these particular forums. So basically each forum will have different sets of articles. Should I be looking for web applications to implement RSS feeds?
Also I couldn't find RSS feeds with images. Is it possible?

P.S. I dont have knowledge in XML language.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You should read this http://feed2.w3.org/docs/rss2.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the RSS feed dynamically and host it somewhere. Given you have a PHP website you already have a "web application" in place. You could build something that reads the forum categories and articles and spits a simple RSS to the screen. Then link your RSS icon (if thats what you are doing) to that page.

Creating an RSS feed is actually very simple.

For instance:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <rss version="2.0">
 <channel>
 <title>The RSS title</title>
 <link>The link to this page, i.e. your feed</link>
 <description>Description for the feed. Some readers use that so make it nice :)</description>

<!-- Repeat as many items as you need, i.e. as the number of your articles -->
 <item>
 <title>Some article title</title>
 <link>http://link/to/article</link>
 <description>Article description, long or short</description>
 <guid>http://webdesign.about.com/rss2.0feed/entry.html</guid>
 <!-- Use enclosures for elements like images audio etc. -->
 <enclosure url="http://url/of/the/pic" length="size_of_the_pic" type="image/jpeg"/>
 </item>
<!-- end repeat -->
 </channel>
 </rss>
```

Here are some online resources that will help you understand:

http://webdesign.about.com/od/rss/a/aa062707.htm
http://www.mnot.net/rss/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

```
my one is like this access the table where the posts is located and broadcast it to the website and put a style sheet to make it look nice 

$strSql = " SELECT
topic_id,
                forum_id,
                post_subject,
                post_time,
                post_text
            FROM
                phpbb_posts
            WHERE
                forum_id in (1,2)
            ORDER BY
                topic_id desc
            limit 0,4
            
            
                ";  
                
    
$recNews = mysqli_query($conn1,$strSql);

$test = mysqli_num_rows($recNews);

      if(empty($test)){
      
      echo '<p> Sorry No topics has been posted at the moment.';
      return;
  }
  else{
    while ($arrNews = mysqli_fetch_array($recNews))
    
    {   
    
    
    
    echo '<div id="tabannouncements">';
    echo '<article class="newsarticle">';
    echo '<header>';
    echo "<li class='newstitle'> Server News *". $arrNews["post_subject"] . " Date:  <date>" . date("d/m/Y",$arrNews["post_time"]) . "</date></li>";
    echo '<div class="newscontent">'.substr($arrNews["post_text"],0, $post_limit).'</p>';
echo '</div>';
echo "\n";
    echo "<b>";
    echo "</b>";

    echo '<p>'.substr($arrNews["post_text"],0, $post_limit).'</p>';
        echo '<br><a href="forum/viewtopic.php?f='.$arrNews['forum_id'].'&amp;t='.$arrNews['topic_id'].'">'.'<input type="submit"  value="Read More"/></a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo "\n";
    echo "<b>";
    echo "</b>";



    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).